# How to enable antialiasing (4X MSAA) for AndroidGameView?

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, xamarin, opentk

I have a simple OpenGL application which I'm trying to enable antialiasing (4x MSAA) for. I can't seem to figure out how to do this using [`AndroidGameView`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aOpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGameView).

So far I've been forcing 4x MSAA through the `Developer Settings` menu as a short term solution but I'd like to be able to do this programmatically. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I also posted this question on the [Xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9726/how-to-enable-4x-msaa-for-androidgameview#latest) but it received no responses so far. Thought I'd try asking on SO since its been asked [before](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8248/androidgameview-antialiasing) over a month ago but still no response.

Comment: Not sure if it is what you need, but `GraphicsMode` has a `Samples` property, which sets how many FSAA samples to use.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks for the lead! `GraphicsMode` only has a getter for the `Samples` property so I found a workaround which is posted as the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the way to do this programmatically is to set the `GraphicsMode` property in the `CreateFrameBuffer()` override of your class inheriting from `AndroidGameView`:

```
    protected override void CreateFrameBuffer()
    {
        // Create a graphics context for OpenGL ES 2.0
        ContextRenderingApi = GLVersion.ES2;

        // Set the graphics mode to use 32bpp colour format, 24bpp depth, 8bpp stencil and 4x MSAA
        GraphicsMode = new GraphicsMode(new ColorFormat(32), 24, 8, 4); 

        // Create the frame buffer itself by calling the base class method
        base.CreateFrameBuffer();

        // Custom initialization code here
    }
```

Thanks to [Cheesebaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368379/cheesebaron) for leading me down the path of looking into the `GraphicsMode` property of `AndroidGameView`.

Comment: Great :) This will be helpful for future reference.